# IndexOutOfBoundsException on List<Address>

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, street-address

In my Android app I have this code:

```
LatLng[] branches;
String[] branchesArray = HomeActivity.branches.toArray(new String[HomeActivity.branches.size()]);

for (int i = 0; i < HomeActivity.branches.size(); i++) {
    branches[i] = getLocationFromAddress(branchesArray[i]);
}
```

getLocationFromAddress method:

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);

        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng((double) (location.getLatitude()), (double) (location.getLongitude()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return p1;
}
```

This code supposed to create an array of `LatLng`, extracted from an array of string addresses. The problem is that whenever I'm running this code, I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` in the log. It refers to line 137 as the problematic line, which is this line:

```
Address location = address.get(0);
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why not just use `HomeActivity.branches.get(i)` instead of `branchesArray[i]`?

Comment: What do you think `location.getLatitude();` and `location.getLongitude();` do?

Answer (score 0):

`getLocationFromName` documentation says:

> returns a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no
>   matches were found or there is no backend service available.

In your case it is returning an empty list, so you should add an additional check:

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);

        if (address == null || address.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = address.get(0);

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return p1;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't need it to return null. I need it to return a `LatLng` object.

Answer (score 0):

The probleme is you are forgetting to initialize "branches" variable with the correct size that's why your are getting "size 0 index 0"

```
String[] branches = HomeActivity.branches.toArray(new String[HomeActivity.branches.size()]);
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. You just copied the line from my code but changed `branchesArray` to `branches`. What's the meaning?

Comment: your loop goes above index 0 and as you initialized String[] branches; your like saying i'm creating an empty array witch size is 0 Arrays are not like List with which you can append indeterminately items without knowing the size ahead. Array in the other hand must be created with a defined size so String branches[] is an array size 0 (empty) and String[] branches = new String[20] is an array that can hold 20 items without having indexOutOfBound issues

Comment: that's why when you loop reach 1 or (in your case i guess 0)
 branches[1] = getLocationFromAddress(branchesArray[1]);
It throw an error because you did tell that the maximum length of you branch var is 1 or even 0 )